# How to properly select the second button using nth-child when there's another element in between the first and the second button?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was trying to use

```
.myDivName button:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

to select my second button in `<div class="myDivName">` but it doesn't work. The code I have is -

```
<div class="myDivName">
  <button>
    1
  </button>
  <input type="text">
  <button>
    2
  </button>
</div>
```

but I found that if I deleted the `<input>` in between, then nth-child would work.

How can I properly select this button using nth-child(2)? If nth-child cannot be used, what's the best way?

Thanks!

fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/e6au4hot/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) instead:

```
.hi > button:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/e6au4hot/9/)

You're concerned with the *type* of element, not the position in the hierarchy